# How can I clear remnants of elements left by jquery slideToggle in FF 5.0

Tags: jquery

I am using slideToggle on several divs.  In Firefox 5.0 the slideToggle works but leaves remnants of the element behind, some chopped text in one case, in another it leaves a partial table.  When I use firebug inspect to see if something is actually there the remnants disappear.  It works fine in IE.  Is there anyway to prevent this?  Has anyone else seen it?

Comment: This is no playframework question.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.destroy();` - without the names of the element I can't use it in context.

Comment: The slideToggle was being called on a fieldset not the parent div.  When I updated to use the div it worked fine.